# How can I install MSSQL driver for PHP 7.0 on OSX?

Tags: sql-server, macos, laravel

I'm trying to connect to an MSSQL database through Laravel 5.4 on OSX. I'm using valet and PHP7.0 but getting `PDOException: could not find driver`. I've done a bit of googling but it looks like a minefield, has anyone managed to do this?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

Comment: Can I safely skip to the setup part considering I already have a PHP ( meets requirements ) install?